# How far does .each read? To the end of the line?

Tags: ruby, file, text, each

Sorry for the newbie question. Was loading a .txt file into the following code:

```
    line_count = 0
    File.open("text.txt").each {|line| line_count += 1}
    puts line_count
```

Does .each simply read until the end of a line before passing its value to the code block? Little explanation would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .each_line to be more explicit, but yes, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-each each reads a line.

```
f = File.new("testfile")
f.each {|line| puts "#{f.lineno}: #{line}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *really* important to read the documentation, because all sorts of things are explained there. For instance, [the documentation for `each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-each) says:

> Executes the block for every line in ios, where lines are separated by sep.

`sep` means "\r", "\n" or "\r\n", depending on the OS the code is running on which is also the value of the special `$/` global variable which contains the default line-ending character for that OS. You can tell Ruby to use a different value for the line-end/separator if you know the file uses something else.

Regarding your code:

I'd do it this way:

```
line_count = 0
File.foreach("text.txt") do |line|
  line_count += 1
end
puts line_count
```

`foreach` is very self-explanatory, which is important when writing code. You want it to be self-documenting as much as possible. `foreach` iterates over "each" line in the file. It also assumes the line-ends are the same as `$/`, but you can force it to be something different, perhaps the letter "z" or "." or " ", depending on your whim and fancy at the moment.